# Replace expression with part of InterpolatingFunction

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I have an `InterpolatingFunction` which returns a 4 dimensional `List` as output. Let's call it `f`. Then I have a mapping such that my variables `{x,y,z,w}` correspond to each of the four elements of the output of the function. I have some complex expressions in `x,y,z,w`, which I want to want to plot using `ParametricPlot`, with `{x,y,z,w}` replaced with `f`. I'm trying something a bit like this:

```
ParametricPlot[
   {
    x^ y - z w^4,
    Sin[x y z w]
    },
   /. {x -> f[t][[1]], y -> f[t][[2]], z -> f[t][[3]], w -> f[t][[4]]}, 
{t, 0, range}]
```

This is not a correct syntax for what I want to do. Can someone advise me how to get this to work?
The expressions `x^ y - z w^4` and `Sin[x y z w]` are less complex than in my real use case.

I would also be interested to know how to convert such a $d$-dimensional `InterpolatingFunction` into $d$ one-dimensional `InterpolatingFunction`s, in case someone comes up with a solution that works differently to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us create some data and interpolate it

```
data = Table[{{t}, {Sin[1 t], Sin[2 t], Sin[3 t], Sin[4 t]}}, {t, 0, 1, 0.01}];
f = Interpolation[data]
```

Now you can do some `ParametricPlot`s

```
ParametricPlot[{x^y - z w^4, Sin[x y z w]} /. {x -> f[t][[1]], 
   y -> f[t][[2]], z -> f[t][[3]], w -> f[t][[4]]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

or simply plot

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

To answer the second part of your question. You can convert such a four-dimensional `InterpolatingFunction` into four one-dimensional ones as follows

Extract data

```
tmesh = f["Coordinates"][[1]];
values = f["ValuesOnGrid"];
```

Re-interpolate

```
Do[
 g[i] = Interpolation[{tmesh, values[[ ;; , i]]} // Transpose],
  {i, Last[Dimensions[values]]}]
```

Plot

```
Plot[{g[1][t], g[2][t], g[3][t], g[4][t]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh so my syntax was correct? I got a bunch of errors when I tried it, maybe they were coming from somewhere else

Comment: @Joe You had one superfluous comma :) But I decided to answer rather than comment your post because of the second part, where you ask about the re-interpolation. This comes often and I hope it will be useful to others too.

Comment: Oh I didn't actually run the code in my post I just wrote roughly the same as my actual usage case. Hopefully it is just a typo in that too. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Or use `Thread[{x, y, z, w} -> f[t]]`